# How to find the exponent of Bessel function related infinite integral?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Please suggest how to find the power law exponent for curvature vs r, I am trying using exponet but it is not working.

```
P1= 10^-10; 
\[Gamma] = 72*10^-3(*surface tension in Newton /m*); 
\[Rho] = 1.0*10^3(*kg/m^3*);
u = \[Gamma]*k^2 + \[Rho]*g; 
c = 3*10^8; g = 9.8; 
w = 105*10^-6;(*beam waist*)
h[r_] := P1*NIntegrate[(Exp[-(w^2*k^2)/8] (k*(BesselJ[0, r*k]))/u),{k,0,5000}]
curvature = Evaluate[D[h[r], {r, 2}]]; 

Exponent[Simplify@curvature,r]
```

Comment: `Exponent` function works only with polynomial.The degree of yours function is `infinity`.

Comment: Let us  not evaluate parameters. Do you mean `Normal[Series[D[h[r], {r, 2}], {r, 0, 1}]] // FullSimplify` which results in $-\frac{k^3 \text{P1} e^{-\frac{1}{8} k^2 w^2}}{2 u}$?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get an idea of asymptotic power-law behavior is to make a log-log plot.

```
LogLogPlot[Abs[curvature] /. k -> 1, {r, 10^-6, 10^6}]
```

[image]

Note that we have to use `Abs` here because `curvature`, as defined, takes on both positive and negative values.

The slope of a log-log graph is, of course, the exponent of the power-law behavior of the function.  From this graph, we can see that $\texttt{curvature} \propto r^0$ (i.e., it approaches a constant) as $r \to 0$, and $\texttt{curvature} \propto r^{-1/2}$ as $r \to \infty$.  (Or, more accurately, it appears to be well-approximated by $f(r)/\sqrt{r}$, where $f(r)$ is an oscillatory function of constant magnitude.)

In fact, this is what you would expect from an expression involving Bessel functions of the first (or second) kind, since it is known that asymptotically
$$
J_n(x) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} \cos \left( x - \frac{n \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right).
$$

Comment: @Seifert, Thanks, How to  calculate exponet if h[r_] := P1*Integrate[Exp[-(w^2*k^2)/8] (k*(BesselJ[0, r*k]))/u,{k,0,5000}]. I also updated the question.